# Reader always returns NULL

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I'm new to C#. I want to write an application that can easily connect to a SQL Server database. I have a separate `DBConnection` class, and I want to call this class from any form.

The problem is that my "reader" always returns `Null`.

```
class DBconnection
{
    private SqlConnection conn;
    private SqlCommand cmd;
    private SqlDataReader rdr;
    private DataTable dt;

    private SqlConnection MyConnection
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.conn == null)
            {
                this.conn = new SqlConnection(DrivingSchool.Properties.Settings.Default.cdsConnectionString);
            }
            return conn;
        }
    }

    private SqlCommand MyCommand
    { 
        get
        {
            if (cmd == null)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand();
                MyCommand.Connection = conn;
            }

            return cmd;
        }
    }

    public DataTable RunQuery(string query)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();

        MyCommand.CommandText = query;
        MyCommand.Connection = conn;
        MyConnection.Open();

        rdr = MyCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        if(rdr.HasRows)
        {
            dt.Load(rdr);
        }

        MyConnection.Close();

        return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that in factoring out the creation of the connection and SqlCommand that you have over-complicated your code.

Comment: The **connection** needs to stay **open** for the duration of using the `SqlDataReader`. Using this separate `DbConnection` class just makes working with ADO.NET unnecessary more complicated, and introduces errors - no a good idea in this case

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that in factoring out the creation of the connection and SqlCommand that you have over-complicated your code.

To fill a DataTable, you should use an SqlDataAdapter (or the appropriate DataAdapter for whatever database you use), something like this:

```
static public DataTable GetDataTableFromQuery(string queryString)
{
    DataTable dt = null;
    string connStr = DrivingSchool.Properties.Settings.Default.cdsConnectionString;

    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connStr))
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    return dt;
}
```